# How to extract file size from youtube-dl in python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, youtube-api, youtube-dl

I'm new to python programming. I want to extract a video/audio size ( any youtube video) before downloading it ??

Comment: Extract? You want to see the various formats and sizes?

Comment: Not various sizes . I only want to print the file size of the video that I'm downloading.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
>>> url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSYxT9GM0fQ'
>>> ytdl = YoutubeDL()
>>> info = ytdl.extract_info(url, download=False)
[youtube] PSYxT9GM0fQ: Downloading webpage
[youtube] PSYxT9GM0fQ: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] PSYxT9GM0fQ: Extracting video information
[youtube] PSYxT9GM0fQ: Downloading DASH manifest
>>> formats = info['formats']
```

formats is a list of dictionaries, pick the format you are looking for

```
>>> format = formats[0]
>>> format['filesize']
2594621
```

In general

```
>>> info.keys()
dict_keys(['extractor_key', 'upload_date', 'thumbnail', 'playlist_index', 'format_id', 'width', 'display_id', 'is_live', 'dislike_count', 'thumbnails', 'annotations', 'age_limit', 'formats', 'id', 'playlist', 'subtitles', 'average_rating', 'player_url', 'height', 'requested_subtitles', 'like_count', 'extractor', 'uploader_id', 'ext', 'automatic_captions', 'format', 'webpage_url', 'end_time', 'uploader', 'webpage_url_basename', 'duration', 'start_time', 'view_count', 'title', 'http_headers', 'description', 'url', 'tags', 'categories'])
```

are the different keys you can use to gain information about the youtube link

Comment: I get `TypeError: extract_info() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'`