# How to set a max file or max resolution for a file in youtubedl

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, youtube-dl

How can I set a max resolution or max file size in youtubedl.

Heres my code:

```
dl_output = {"outmpl": "C:/Users/12488/Downloads/Instabot/Downloads/%(title)s.%(ext)s"}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(dl_output) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ'])
```

How can I set a limit for file size or file resolution, also how can I print the file size or resolution in the console.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32121060/14316282

Comment: It's 5 years old so perhaps not